# Lua How to tell 1 from 1.0

Tags: types, lua, integer, double, lua-5.2

I have a configuration script where the user can enter values either as an absolute value or a percentage value.

Absolute values are written as a value between 0.0 and 1.0 while percentage value are written as 0 to 100.

How can I distinguish 1 from 1.0?
If I were to use strings, then it's not a problem for sure...
I would like to keep this configuration simple and not have to rely strings.

Is this possible at all?

RECAP:

```
a = 1
b = 1.0
```

How to tell that `a` is not of the same type as `b`.

***EDIT***
The configuration file look something like this:

```
local config = {}

-- A lot of comments describing how to configure

config.paramA = 1
config.paramB = 1.0

return config
```

In my processing script i read the configs like this:

```
config = require 'MyConfigFile'

config.paramA
config.paramB
```

Comment: How are you reading the file? Can you just use the string value before converting to numbers for normal usage? And then "tag" the value somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726958/query-lua-userdata-type-from-c

Comment: @jean no this is not userdata accessed from C/C++ I need to do this in Lua script on a number Lua type.

Comment: What if the user wants to write in a percentage value with a decimal in it, like 12.5? Have you considered allowing only absolute values or only percentages?You said your goal is simplicity and IMHO having 1 and 1.0 mean different things is very confusing.

Comment: If it was a string this wouldn't be a problem at all, I just wanted to know if it was possible without strings. As @Youka mentioned, it is possible in Lua 5.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With **Lua 5.3** came the *integer* data type which allows to differ between integer & floating point numbers and provides better performance in some cases. [math.type](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.type) is the function to get the subtype of a number.

```
local x = 1.0
print(math.type(x)) -- float
x = 1
print(math.type(x)) -- integer
```

If your percent value should be floating point too, **William** already called it: "a number is a number". You have to add an additional information to your number to differentiate, like packing it in a table with an identifier. Because you have just 2 cases, a boolean would be a cheap solution.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting solution, but i forgot to add the tag Lua 5.2. I have no control over the Lua version used :(

Comment: I marked this as the solution because it is possible, in Lua 5.3 at least. However, for my own problem I can't use this solution. I have to fallback on my plan B to use strings instead.

Comment: @MaxKielland If you care about performance, doing a string->number conversion isn't a very smart solution. In case of your Lua interpreter is [luajit](http://luajit.org/) a table may even be optimized to something cheaper than your string solution.

Answer (score 4):

From [PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html) you can see that a number is a number and therefore there's no way to distinguish `1` from `1.0` when working with them because they do have the same type

A way to to solve your problem is using a table that contains both the value and the type:

```
config.paramA = { 1, 'i' }
config.paramB = { 1.0, 'd' }
```

Or using a string and parsing it before converting to an integer:

```
config.paramA = '1'
config.paramB = '1.0'
```

Comment: As I already said, if it was a string there wouldn't be a problem at all ;) The table thing is an interesting solution but it makes it more complicated. Then a string with just '100%' or '1' would be much easier for the user.

Answer (score 2):

With Lua 5.1 and 5.2 there is no difference, which can be seen from `luac` output (`luac -i`) as `local a, b = 1, 1.0` generates the following code:

```
main <1.lua:0,0> (3 instructions, 12 bytes at 007D04E8)
0+ params, 2 slots, 0 upvalues, 2 locals, 1 constant, 0 functions
    1   [1] LOADK       0 -1    ; 1
    2   [1] LOADK       1 -1    ; 1
    3   [1] RETURN      0 1
```

Lua 5.3 allows to distinguish between the two using [math.type](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.type) as they have different subtypes.

As a solution to your particular problem, if you really want to make it a non-integer, you can probably add a very small delta to the number: `1.0000001` instead of `1.0`.

Comment: This is also an interesting solution, but it complicates it for the user to understand why they have to add so many decimals. I think I will use my next backup plan to use a String with a % sign instead.

Answer (score 1):

some suggestions:

1) allow only one of the two formats

2) use a function to make the format explicit

```
config.paramA = percent(1.9)
config.paramB = portion(1)
```

those functions could create tables with type info or just convert the value to a consistent type

Comment: I like this idea too :) it is clean and simple to understand.

Comment: Another suggestion: use different keys. E.g. `config.paramA = 1` vs. `config.paramA_percent = 1`. Using some metatable tricks both can write to the same field.